# No Such Variable When Using While Loop in Expect

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm attempting to access a variable within a while loop in expect, but I keep getting an error that the variable doesn't exist. The code in question:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ./simulator.sh
set timeout 1

...<extra code>...

# Return the time in seconds from epoch
proc getTime {year month day hour minute} {
    set rfc_form ${year}-${month}-${day}T${hour}:${minute}
    set time [clock scan $rfc_form]
    return $time
}

# Get a handle to the file to store the log output
set fileId [open $filename "a"]
# Get one line at a time
expect -re {.*the number of lines from the debug log file to appear on one page.*}
send "1\r"
# Get the initial time stamp and store the first line
expect -re {^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})\..*$} {
    puts -nonewline $fileId $expect_out(0,string)
    set initTime $expect_out(1,string) $expect_out(2,string) $expect_out(3,string) $expect_out(4,string) $expect_out(5,string)
}
send "1\r"
# Iterate over the logs until we get at least 5 minutes worth of log data
while { true } {
    expect -re {^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})\..*$} {
        puts -nonewline $fileId $expect_out(0,string)
        set currentTime $expect_out(1,string) $expect_out(2,string) $expect_out(3,string) $expect_out(4,string) $expect_out(5,string)
    }
    # 300 = 5 minutes * 60 seconds
    if { $initTime - $currentTime > 300 } break
    expect -re {.*enter.*}
    send "n\r"
}

...<extra code>...
```

And the error I get is:

```
$ ./test.sh
the number of lines from the debug log file to appear on one page1
201505151624.00 721660706 ns | :OCA (027):MAIN (00) | CONTROL |START LINE
enter1
201505151620.00 022625203 ns | :OCA (027):MAIN (00) | CONTROL |com.citrix.cg.task.handlers.ADDeltaSyncHandler:ThreadID:1182, Delta sync on:activedirectory2
entercan't read "initTime": no such variable
    while executing
"if { $initTime - $currentTime > 300 } break"
    ("while" body line 7)
    invoked from within
"while { true } {
        expect -re {^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})\..*$} {
                puts -nonewline $fileId $expect_out(0,string)
                set currentTime $expect_o..."
    (file "./test.sh" line 42)
```

I'm sure I'm doing something incredibly stupid, but I can't figure it out for the life of me. Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expect pattern has not matched:

```
expect -re {^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})\..*$} {
    puts -nonewline $fileId $expect_out(0,string)
    set initTime $expect_out(1,string) $expect_out(2,string) $expect_out(3,string) $expect_out(4,string) $expect_out(5,string)
}
```

You would know if it did match because you would get a syntax error: the `set` command takes only one or two arguments, and you have given it 6.

Add `exp_internal 1` to a line before the spawn command, and expect will show you verbose debugging to let you know how your patterns are or are not matching.

To solve the `set` syntax error, you probably want

```
    set initTime [getTime $expect_out(1,string) $expect_out(2,string) $expect_out(3,string) $expect_out(4,string) $expect_out(5,string)]
```

Also, in the `if` condition, be aware that `$initTime` will be *smaller* than `$currentTime` , so `{$initTime - $currentTime > 300}` will never be true, so your loop will be infinite.

Comment: First off, thank you so much for taking the time to respond--this was immensely helpful in seeing that I was way off in left field. The verbose debugging was the key here as it showed that the input I was receiving did NOT start with the digits I expected but rather a new line command, so my match (as you aptly pointed out) did not match. I also updated my set command to be syntactically correct. Lastly, I updated the variable names from initTime and currentTime to startTime and previousTime respectively to make it a little clearer to future devs that the time is in reverse chronological order